# Wordpress, Alternating float on featured image

Tags: css

I want each loop on a specific category to alternate float on the "featured image". So that each new post the "featured image" change float (right side, left side).

I use folowing code to pull odd or even classes on each post,

```
<?php query_posts('showposts=5&cat=5,'); if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php $c = 0; ?>
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
       <div <?php post_class((++$c % 2 === 0) ? 'odd' : 'even'); ?>>
       <h2 class="entry-title"><a>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'twentyten' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
<div class="featuredImage">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail('medium'); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; wp_reset_query();?>
```

Then I was trying to change the float on the "featured image" with css on the different post classes (odd or even). Se example,

```
.even { width:650px; height:250px; background-color: #000;}

.odd{ width:650px; height:250px; background-color: #616161;}
.odd, .featuredImage{ float:left;}
.even, .featuredImage{ float:right;}
```

My example, http://fskador.se/myPerformanceLast/?page_id=49

But cant get it to work!! please help!

Answer (score 0):

Incorrect

```
<h2 class="entry-title"><a>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'twentyten' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
```

Corrected

```
<h2 class="entry-title"><a title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'twentyten' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
```

**CSS**

Incorrect

```
.odd, .featuredImage{ float:left;}
.even, .featuredImage{ float:right;}
```

Corrected

```
div.odd .featuredImage{ float:left;} 
div.even .featuredImage{ float:right;}
```

Or

```
.odd .featuredImage{ float:left;}
.even .featuredImage{ float:right;}
```